# sql pair two results in two different column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

im working on an exercice in sql :
the database is :

> Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
> English: There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a >director.
>
> Reviewer ( rID, name )
> English: The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.
>
> Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )
> English: The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on >a certain ratingDate.

they used this query to combine the same result in two clomns:

```
select distinct (select name 
from reviewer 
where rid = r1.rid) as n1, 
(select name 
 from reviewer 
  where rid = r2.rid)
  from rating r1 join rating r2 using (mid)
   where r1.rid <> r2.rid and (select name 
    from reviewer 
    where r1.rid = rid) < (select name 
    from reviewer 
    where rid = r2.rid)
  order by n1
```

i dont get this part how it works or what does it mean:

```
     r1.rid <> r2.rid and (select name 
                        from reviewer 
                        where r1.rid = rid) < (select name 
                                               from reviewer 
                                               where rid = r2.rid)
```

Comment: the query we are searching for :For all pairs of reviewers such that both reviewers gave a rating to the same movie, return the names of both reviewers. Eliminate duplicates, don't pair reviewers with themselves, and include each pair only once. For each pair, return the names in the pair in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r1.rid <> r2.rid` right now you have a join against the reviewer table, which is aliased as `r1` and `r2`. `r1.rid <> r2.rid` means "from both aliases, make sure you're getting the one where the IDs are different."

```
(select name 
 from reviewer 
 where r1.rid = rid) < (select name 
                        from reviewer 
                        where rid = r2.rid)
```

You're retrieving the first instance of the name among any potential duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`r1.rid <> r2.rid` means `r1.rid NOT EQUAL TO r2.rid`

AND

```
(select name from reviewer
where r1.rid = rid)        < (select name from reviewer
                                 where rid = r2.rid)
```

means

`get reviewer name whose value is less than other`

Basically both conditions are to check that you don't get any repetitive value

Also note if you remove any of your conditions you might get duplicate/double entries